# Controlling <iframe> time through URL

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

`#t=3m05s` at the end of the url, should make the video play @ 3 minute 5th second.

In this example the url is present, but it doesn't start from the 9th minute. The video, however, plays fine. The question is why?

```
<iframe id="Iframe1" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EgBWDPXF2gU?autoplay=1#t=9m05s&origin=http://example.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Seems strange to me to have the `&` to be present _after_ the `#`.

Comment: just use seconds http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgBWDPXF2gU&feature=player_embedded&t=1341

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the start parameter instead, it's calculated in seconds

```
<iframe id="Iframe1" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EgBWDPXF2gU?autoplay=1&start=545&origin=http://example.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: No problemo, please mark it the question as solved if you have no more issues